# UBUNTU 12.04 and Lubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I've had Ubuntu 12.04 installed since 2014 with no need, reason, or desire to upgrade. But now that it's coming to EOL I have installed Lubuntu, using this method sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core. My question is Lubuntu just a different desktop environment, with 12.04 at the core, when it reaches EOL will it no longer be secure? This is an old laptop that can't be upgraded to 14.04. And I don't want to start from scratch if I don't have to.

Comment: That is correct. You will have 12.04 with a different desktop environment. Why can't it be upgraded to 14.04 ? Usually there is no reason for not upgrading. And why not upgrading to 16.04 ?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. You will have the same Ubuntu Core with a different Desktop Environment.

You should upgrade your System to the current LTS (16.04). There is usually no reasons why you cannot do this, the [system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/) did not change a lot in past years.

- [12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_Requirements): 700MHz, 384MB Ram (32 Bit) / 512MB (64 Bit)
- [Current](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/): 700MHz, 512MB Ram

Upgrading between LTS usually works with no problems:

Change `Prompt=never` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` to `Prompt=lts`

and then run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Any info I could find for minimum requirements for 14.04 is a 2core machine. This is a single core HP with Intel Celeron processor 1.6 GHz and 2MB of memory.

Comment: Dual Core is the Recommended System Requirements. The minimal requirements are way lower and should not be much different from 12.04 (Ubuntu makes no difference on their homepage) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/

Comment: Well, maybe I'll go ahead and try it.  I miss pressed my fingers, the memory is 2 GB not MB. Now should I remove the Lubuntu, then upgrade to 14.04, then reinstall Lubuntu? Or would it matter?

Comment: You don't need to remove Lubuntu.

Comment: @Don_S Since you are a reputation 1 user: If this post answered your question please consider accepting it as an answer.